# Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value

Tags: sql, asp.net, ado.net

В чем ошибка?

```
string s = Page.User.Identity.Name.ToString();
            if (Page.User.Identity.Name != "")
            {
                connectionString = WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["OSBR"].ConnectionString;
                con = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
                con.Open();
                cmd = con.CreateCommand();
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT TOP(20) * FROM dbo.ReturnTable WHERE SiteID=" + s + "ORDER BY id DESC", con);
                reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                if (reader.Read())
                {
                    ReturnGrid.DataSource = reader;
                    ReturnGrid.DataBind();
                }
                reader.Close();
 
            }
            else
                Response.Redirect("Login.aspx");
```

Если SiteID=MKS то

```
string s = "MKS";
string sql = "SELECT TOP(20) * FROM dbo.ReturnTable WHERE SiteID=" + s + "ORDER BY id DESC";
```

Выбрать 20 строк где SiteID =MKS в обратном порядке. Нет?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вряд ли ещё остались спецы по таким древним технологиям, как ASP и ADO. Зато тут есть спецы по ASP.NET и ADO.NET, но они не увидят ваш вопрос, потому что меток нет.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov актуализировал

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov Спасибо

Answer (score 0, accepted):

А вот потому что надо делать не конкатенацию строк для формирования sql-запроса, а нормальный запрос с параметрами.

Comment: @Qwerty вы имеете ввиду что-то типа
```
 cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT login FROM Users WHERE SiteID=@SiteID and password=@password", con);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SiteID", int.Parse(Login1.UserName));
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", int.Parse(Login1.Password));
```

Comment: @Qwerty А где в моем коде конкатенация? Я просто не через явные параметры вывожу. Насколько я понимаю конкатенация это объединение чего либо(строк, значений)

Comment: @ЕвгенийНейфельд, да.

Comment: стоило опубликовать это как комментарий, а не ответ.

Comment: @Qweriy чем помогут параметры в решении моей проблемы?

Comment: @Qweriy мне уже ответили на другом форуме. Что из-за отсутствия параметров идет не правильное сравнение значений в базе. СПАСИБО

Comment: @ЕвгенийНейфельд, параметры помогут тем, что в твоём коде строка подставляется не только без экранирования, но и даже без кавычек.

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin, нет, в данном случае это именно ответ.

Comment: @Qweriy да так и ответили
В данном случае получается неверный запрос потому что
а) запись SiteID=MKS означает сравнение двух колонок. А вам нужно сравнение колонки со строкой. Одинарные кавычки нужно было добавить.